# How to code a "retry" logic (with only 1 iteration) in F# without mutable vars?

Tags: f#, refactoring

So by trying to avoid mutable variables, I came up with the following retry-logic code, which seems ugly:

```
let result = TryConnect()
match result with
| ErrorConnecting ->
    SetupConnectionParameters()
    let resultAgain = TryConnect()
    match resultAgain with
    | ErrorConnecting ->
                      Console.Error.WriteLine("Setup failed!")
                      Environment.Exit(7)
    | Success(value) -> PerformOperations(value)
| Success(value) -> PerformOperations(value)
```

Is there a way to reduce some duplication here? (Remember, no `mutable` vars.)
Thanks!

Comment: use recursion - have a parameter which is true on the first try and false on the second.

Comment: 6 answers. what a can of worms you opened....:-)

Answer (score 12):

Since there are a  lot of alternatives being shown here, here is another one:

```
let private tryConnectNth n = 
    if n <> 0 then SetupConnectionParameters()
    TryConnect()

let isSuccess = function
    |Success _ -> true
    |ErrorConnecting -> false

let tryConnect n =
    Seq.init n tryConnectNth // generate a sequence of n connection attempts
    |> Seq.tryFind isSuccess // try to find the first success - returns Option
    |> Option.fold (fun _ -> id) ErrorConnecting // return ErrorConnecting if None, or result otherwise
```

It calls `SetupConnectionParameters()` only on a non-zero connection attempt and repeats up to n times.

Answer (score 8):

Make the function recursive with a parameter for retries:

```
let rec private tryToConnectAux tryAgain =
    match TryConnect() with
    | Success(value) -> PerformOperations(value)
    | ErrorConnecting when tryAgain ->
        SetupConnectionParameters ()
        tryToConnectAux false
    | ErrorConnecting ->
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Setup failed!")
        Environment.Exit(7)
```

Call via `tryToConnectAux true`.

---

This answer was edited. Original code:

```
let rec tryConnecting nRetries =
    match TryConnect() with
    | ErrorConnecting ->
        if nRetries > 0 then tryConnecting (nRetries - 1)
        else
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Setup failed!")
            Environment.Exit(7)
    | Success(value) -> PerformOperations(value)
```

(This version doesn't include `SetupConnectionParameters()`, you have to add it at whatever location is appropriate)

Comment: if I call SetupConnectionParameters() before calling `tryConnecting` then I'm calling it always. I only want to call SetupConnectionParameters() if it fails once (if it fails twice, exit)

Comment: @ympostor wow, quite some activity here. I edited the answer to match the behavior you're looking for, and cut a line via a `when` clause.

Answer (score 8):

You could separate out the retry logic into a separate function. Here's an example with lots of printing to console to illustrate what's happening.

```
let rec retry f tries =
    printfn "Trying..."
    match f () with
    | Some successValue ->
        printfn "Success"
        Some successValue
    | None ->
        match tries with
        | [] ->
            printfn "Failed"
            None
        | delayMs :: rest ->
            printfn "Waiting %i ms..." delayMs
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delayMs:int)
            retry f rest

let random = System.Random()

let connect () =
    if random.Next(100) < 30 then Some "connection"
    else None

match retry connect [100; 100] with
| Some connection -> printfn "Do something with connection."
| None -> printfn "Could not connect."
```

Try running the last expression a few times.

- This gives you a flexible number of attempts with an optional delay after each (the number of delays provided is the number of retries).
- It should be possible to adapt your code to use the `retry` function. You need to make a function that attempts to connect once and returns the connection wrapped in `Some` if it succeeds, or just `None` if it fails. Then pass that function in as the `f` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

While I appreciate @Vandroiy's try, his block doesn't exactly behave like my original code (because I intentionally don't want to call `SetupConnectionParameters()` the first time).

This is my result, inspired in his answer and Jon's initial hint:

```
let rec TryConnectAndMaybeSetup(retries) =
    if (retries > 1) then
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Setup failed")
        Environment.Exit(7)

    let result = TryConnect()
    match result with
    | ErrorConnecting ->
        SetupConnectionParameters()
        TryConnectAndMaybeSetup(retries + 1)
    | Success(value) -> PerformOperations(value)

TryConnectAndMaybeSetup(0)
```

This alternative is also simpler than @TheQuickBrownFox's.

Comment: Of course the simplest way would be to use mutation and there's nothing wrong with mutation with limited scope.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution based on Vandroiy's solution, which only calls the setup function upon the first failure.

```
let tryConnecting = 
    let rec connect nRetries setupFunction =
        match TryConnect() with
        | ErrorConnecting ->
            if nRetries > 0 then 
                setupFunction()
                connect (nRetries - 1) setupFunction
            else
                Console.Error.WriteLine("Setup failed!")
                Environment.Exit(7)
        | Success(value) -> PerformOperations(value)
    connect 1 SetupConnectionParameters
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an iterative solution, based on the `Seq.unfold` function.  We use this function to generate a lazy sequence of Success/Failed events.  We can then perform manipulations on this sequence to get the successful result, or stop after a number of retries.

First let us define the signature of the function that could fail:

```
type ActionResult<'a> = 
    | Success of 'a
    | ErrorConnecting

type getValue<'a> = unit -> ActionResult<'a>
```

Then define a discrimianted union which models all the different states we could be in with regards to retrying:

```
type Retry<'a> = 
    | Success of 'a * int
    | Failure of int
    | Untried
```

Now, given the result of the last retry, we generate the next item in the sequence:

```
let unfolder (functionInvoke : getValue<_>) (retryParameters : Retry<_>) : ((Retry<_>* Retry<_>) option) = 

    let nextRetryResult () = 
        match functionInvoke() with
        | ActionResult.ErrorConnecting -> 
            match retryParameters with
            | Untried -> Failure 1
            | Failure pastRetries -> Failure (pastRetries + 1)
        | ActionResult.Success value -> 
            match retryParameters with
            | Untried -> Success (value, 0 )
            | Failure pastRetries -> Success (value, pastRetries )

    match retryParameters with
        | Untried 
        | Failure _ -> Some(retryParameters, nextRetryResult() )
        | success -> Some(retryParameters, success)
```

We can now use this function to create the `getResultWithRetries` function:

```
let isNotSuccessAndLimitNotReached limit (retry : Retry<'a>) = 
    match retry with
    | Untried -> true
    | Failure retryCount when retryCount < limit -> true
    | _ -> false

let getResultWithRetries limit getValue   = 
    Seq.unfold (unfolder getValue) Retry.Untried 
    |> Seq.skipWhile(isNotSuccessAndLimitNotReached limit)
    |> Seq.head
```

We can finally test this:

```
let successValue = getResultWithRetries 3 (fun () -> ActionResult.Success "ABC")
let ``fail after 3 attempts`` : Retry<string> = getResultWithRetries 3 (fun () -> ActionResult.ErrorConnecting)
let ``fail after 5 attempts`` : Retry<string> = getResultWithRetries 5 (fun () -> ActionResult.ErrorConnecting)
```

Using the following function, we can test what happens with impure functions:

```
let succeedOn count = 
  let mutable callCount = 0
  let f () = 
    match callCount < count with
    | true -> 
      callCount <- callCount + 1
      ErrorConnecting
    | false -> ActionResult.Success "ABC"
  f


let ``result after 3 attempts when succeeds on 2nd`` : Retry<string> = getResultWithRetries 3 (succeedOn 2)
let ``result after 3 attempts when succeeds on 5th`` : Retry<string> = getResultWithRetries 3 (succeedOn 5)
```